# Dagger 2 Component with differently scoped modules

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

## Context

I have two Dagger 2 modules:

1. `NetworkModule`, with `@Singleton` scope, that provides an HTTP client;
2. `ApiModule`, with a custom `@UserScope` scope, that uses the HTTP client to create a consumer for Github's API.

Then, I create a Dagger 2 component, to provide the Retrofit client.

#### NetworkModule.kt

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpClient(): OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
}
```

#### ApiModule.kt

```
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])
class ApiModule(private val user: String) {

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    fun provideApi(httpClient: OkHttpClient): GithubApi = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()
            .create(GithubApi::class.java)
}
```

#### ApiComponent.kt

```
@Component(modules = [ApiModule::class])
@UserScope
interface ApiComponent {
    fun inject(target: GithubRetriever)
}
```

## Issue

When I try to build the application, if I add the `@UserScope` scope to the `ApiComponent` then I get the following error message:

```
e: ApiComponent.java:4: error: ApiComponent scoped with @UserScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
e: 
e: @dagger.Component(modules = {ApiModule.class})
e: ^
e:       @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull @Singleton @Provides okhttp3.OkHttpClient NetworkModule.provideHttpClient()
```

The same happens if I use `@Singleton` scope instead of `@UserScope`.

How should I declare the `ApiComponent` in order to have a successful build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single module cannot reference two scopes; which is what is happening when you include the `NetworkModule` in the `ApiModule` (`@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])`).

However, a module can *depend* on a component that uses a different scope.

```
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class])
@Singleton
interface NetworkComponent

@Component(dependencies = [NetworkComponent::class], modules = [ApiModule::class])
interface ApiComponent {
    fun inject(target: GithubRetriever)        
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment by mistake. I was asking if we need to create a different component for each differently scoped module. Thank you for your comment, I'm going to apply your suggestions to my code

Comment: I created the `NetworkComponent` and added it as a dependency to the `ApiComponent`, as you suggested, but I still get the very same issue. I also tried to remove the `includes = [NetworkModule::class]` from the `ApiModule`'s `@Module` annotation, but in this case I get another error `okhttp3.OkHttpClient cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method` because the `ApiModule` cannot "see" the `OkHttpClient` provided by the `NetworkModule`

Comment: No worries. Yes, you should have at least one component for each scope (multiple components can have the same scope) ([see Singletons and Scoped Bindings](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html)). Another method for dealing with multiple scopes is to use [subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html), though I don't have much experience with subcomponents.

Comment: Hm, you would need to remove `includes = [NetworkModule::class]` from the `ApiModule`; but I'm not sure why you're getting this new error. Are you trying to reference the `OkHttpClient` from somewhere other than the `ApiModule`? Try cleaning and rebuilding your project too.

Comment: I fixed by adding to the `NetworkComponent` the following method: `fun httpClient(): OkHttpClient`. In this way the `NetworkComponent` is able to provide the missing dependency