# Dagger 2 and component dependency in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Activity

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivityComponent
```

Application

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    HttpModule::class,
    ApplicationModule::class
])
interface AppComponent
```

Activity Specific

```
@Component(
        modules = [LandingModule::class],
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class, ActivityComponent::class]
)
@ActivityContext
interface LandingComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

Apply

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DaggerLandingComponent.builder().build().inject(this)
   }
```

The error I'm getting is that AppComponent has a singleton scope
`cannot depend on scoped components:`

What's the proper solution in this case?

Comment: can I see your application module and http module?

Comment: I think I had a very similar use case in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078519/dagger-2-component-with-differently-scoped-modules EDIT: maybe it was not "very similar", but still it may help you ;)

Comment: If you want an answer to _What's the proper solution in this case?_ you should explain what it is that you're trying to do and achieve. Add an explanation why you need component dependencies, why subcomponents won't work, and also include some sample code or description of what the components do. The way I see it you can merge your Activity and Landing component, to make it a subcomponent like most of us do.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to address this is to add a `plus` method to your parent component. So `ActivityComponent` is technically `AppComponent` + `ActivityComponent` and `LandingComponent` is `AppComponent` + `ActivityComponent` + `LandingComponent`.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    HttpModule::class,
    ApplicationModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    ActivityComponent plus(module: ActivityModule)
}

@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivityComponent {
    LandingComponent plus(module: LandingModule)
}

@ActivityContext
@Subcomponent(modules = [LandingModule::class])
interface LandingComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

Apply

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    AppComponent.builder().build().plus(ActivityModule()).plus(LandingModule())
}
```

Comment: +1, though "plus methods" by that name are more closely associated with Dagger 1, even though that exact syntax works for Dagger 2. Future readers might learn more in the Dagger 2 documentation by searching for "subcomponents", as in the [Dagger User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents) or on the [Component documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#subcomponents).